# Suppose the function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is onto. Prove or disprove that the induced map $\bar f^{-1}: P(Y) \rightarrow P(X)$ is onto

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Suppose the function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is onto. Prove or disprove that the induced map $\bar f^{-1}: P(Y) \rightarrow P(X)$ is onto.

This is a powerset ---> $\bar f^{-1}: P(Y) \rightarrow P(X)$

The $\bar f$ means the set function induced by $f$.

my attempt:

The function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is onoto which means that it's a surjection.

The surjection definition is $(\forall Y) (\exists X)(f(x)=y)$

Suppose we want to disprove this statement. Let $f: [1,2,3] \rightarrow [a,b,c]$ be defined by $f(1) = a, f(2) = 1,$ and $f(3)=b$

For the inverses, we have $f^{-1}(a) = 1, f^{-1}(a) = 2$, and $f^{-1}(b) = 3$

Definition 5.3.1 states that we let $f: X \rightarrow Y$. THe set function induced by $f$ is the function $\bar f P(X) \rightarrow P(Y)$ defined by the rule that for all $A \in P(x)$

$\bar f[1,2,3] =[a,b]$

$\bar f[2,3] =[a,b]$

Definition 5.3.8 states that we let $f: X \rightarrow Y$. For each set $B \in P(Y)$ define the function $\bar f^{-1}: P(Y) \rightarrow P(X) $ by $ \bar f^{-1}(B)=[x \in x: f(x) \in B]$.

$\bar f^{-1}[a,b] = [1,2,3]$

The $\bar f^{-1}$ will never equal to $[2,3]$.

$\bar f^{-1} [a,b] = [2,3] \neq f^{-1} [a,a,b] =[1,2,3]$

Therefore $\bar f^{-1}$ is not onto (not a surjection).

Is this correct?

Comment: If you take $X$ to have larger cardinality than $Y$, then certainly no map from $P(Y)$ to $P(X)$ can be onto.

Comment: like if X was [1,2,3] and Y was only [a,b] then it wouldn't be onto?

Comment: @Nate True if $X$ is finite, not necessarily true if $Y$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=\{1,2\}$, $Y=\{1\}$, and $f(1)=f(2)=1$.

Not true in general.

Then 
$$
\mathscr P(X)=\big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\big\}
$$
and
$$
\mathscr P(Y)=\big\{\varnothing,\{1\}\big\}
$$
Clearly
$$
f^{-1}(\varnothing)=\varnothing\quad\text{and}\quad f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1,2\}.
$$
Thus $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ DO NOT belong to the range of the inverse image $f^{-1}$

Comment: (Reposting, to fix a typo.) 
 
Even easier: $|X|=2$, $|Y|=1$, so there is a surjection from $X$ to $Y$, but $|\mathcal P(Y)|=2$, $|\mathcal P(X)|=4$, so there can be no surjection from $\mathcal P(Y)$ to $\mathcal P(X)$, regardless of whether it is $f^{−1}$ for some $f$.